# Guardar input dinamico en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, array

Buen día a todos

Estoy intentando guardar un input dinámico y un select igual dinamico pero no logro hacerlo
[image: Imagen se mis select e input]

esto es mi vista de lo que quiero guardar

los logro guardar así

```
            $name =  $request->title;
            $description =  $request->seldimen;

            $count = count($name);

             for($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++){
                $objModel = new EstructuraFinal();
                $objModel->nombre_estructuraf = $name[$i];
                $objModel->id_indice = $indice;
                $objModel->id_area = $area;
                $objModel->id_departamento = $departamento;
                $objModel->id_dimension = $description[$i];
                $objModel->save();
             }
```

pero solo me funciona la primera vez cuando mi tabla esta en blanco y después me pone este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

revise en valor de mis input y select y si me retorna valores pero no me lo guarda, la linea de error que marca es esta `$objModel->nombre_estructuraf = $name[$i];`

htlm del form

```
                        @foreach($estructura as $estructura)
                            <tr id="formato{{$estructura->id_estructura}}">
                                <th scope="row">{{$estructura->id_estructura}}</th>
                                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="title[{{$estructura->id_estructura}}]" value="{{$estructura->nombre_estructura}}"></td>
                                <td>
                                    <select class="form-control" name="seldimen[{{$estructura->id_estructura}}]">
                                        <option selected disabled>Selecciona una opción</option>
                                        @foreach($dimensiones as $dimen)
                                            <option value="{{$dimen->id_dimension}}">{{$dimen->nombre_dimension}}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-delete delete-producto" value="{{$estructura->id_estructura}}">Eliminar</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
```

espero puedan ayudarme gracias

Comment: Enseñanos el html del form.

Comment: Listo ya lo añadí en la pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya lo solucione si a alguien le sirve lo solucione así

```
            $nombre = $request->input('title');
            $dimension = $request->input('seldimen');


            foreach ($request->input('title') as $key => $value) { 
                $objModel = new EstructuraFinal();
                $objModel->nombre_estructuraf = $nombre[$key];
                $objModel->id_indice = $indice;
                $objModel->id_area = $area;
                $objModel->id_departamento = $departamento;
                $objModel->id_dimension = $dimension[$key];
                $objModel->save();   
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo para ayudar a quien tenga un error similar.

Básicamente el problema es que los índices del array no están consecutivos 0,1,2,3...y por eso truena el for porque se encuentra con un 0,2,3,5,6 (falta el 1 y el 4) cuando llega la variable $i al valor 1 sale el error.

En este caso lo solucionaste por el foreach porque no ibas recorriendo los índices.

Comment: Puedes por favor argumentar tu respuesta? Cómo sabes que los índices están como dices?

Comment: Por experiencia. Hace unos días tuve ese problema. La única forma de comprobarlo es que repliques un array como el que digo y hagas un for para recorrerlo.